# How to write a .sh that get process id of application and then stop the application?

Tags: sh

for example, I need to use a app called SomeApp, but it often needs to restart, so I need to type "ps -ef | grep SomeApp" and then "kill -9 7777"
which first find the process id and then stop that process:

```
XXXX:~ XXXX$ ps -ef | grep SomeApp
333  7777     1   0  1:40PM ??         0:40.31 /Users/XXXX/SomeApp
333  8888  9999   0  1:58PM abcd000    0:00.00 grep SomeApp
XXXX:~ XXXX$ kill -9 7777
```

now I want to put the command into .sh, but I have something don't know how to write in .sh:

1. exclude the result that belongs to my grep action
2. get the correct line result
3. get the second argument (process id) of result string

can anyone help?

Comment: Alternatively, [killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) allows you to kill process(es) by name...

Answer (score 1):

This'll do it.

```
ps -ef | grep 'SomeApp' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Or look at `pgrep` and `pkill` depending on the OS.